# Multiple SVC references each exposing same entities

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4

I have a WPF application that uses a WCF services to perform operations on entities using EF4.
My project structure is as follows:

Project: EntityObjects

- this is where the edmx file lives

Project: WCFService

- References EntityObjects
- Has data contracts to perform actions on entities
- Has three different svc files, called Partner.svc, Section.svc, Scheme.svc

Project: DataLayer

- has service references to Partner.svc, section.svc, scheme.svc

The problem is that the DataLayer project then has ambiguous references to objects as each svc file returns its own references of the entity objects.

How do I get around this?

Comment: so you have entity objects that are common to multiple services?

Comment: Yes, there is one edmx that is used by all three services

Comment: I think that I shouldn't have three different services but rather one. I'm just trying to fix up a badly designed project and trying to preserve as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work this way. If you want to have same data contract types among all three service references you must use [data contract sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628653.aspx). That means that your data contracts must be provided to client project in separate assembly prior to adding service references. Most often this means that you will share data contract assembly between server and client. In your case it means sharing EntityObjects with whole EF stuff - that is bad.

There are multiple solutions:

- Placing entities and EDMX stuff into separate projects and share only project with entities
- Use custom Data transfer objects instead of entities as data contracts and share assembly with these DTO
- Don't share assembly and instead create "copy" of data contracts manually for client
- Don't expose same entities through different services
- Use only single service if it makes sense in your architecture

Last two choices are more about architecture of your application.

Comment: This definitely is a real world problem and thanks for listing down the possible workarounds. I however think there should be a better fix for this, a solution instead of workaround. Something MS can build in into VS tooling (if not in WCF itself)

Answer (score 0):

You could :

Build a wrapper class that wrapped access to all 3 services. Then reference the objects concerned in the DataLayer project directly rather than through the service and convert as required in the wrapper class.